# Bookmarklet gives me syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, bookmarklet

I'm having a problem with a bookmarklet. You see, when I excecute this code normally and without compression it works, but when I compress it and put it in a bookmark it throws an unexpected ; error.

*Uncompressed*:

```
javascript:(
    listOfServers = [ "Vodlocker" , "Played" , "MovShare" , "NowVideo" ];
    for( var i = 0 ; i < listOfServers.length ; i ++ ){ 
            var currentServer = listOfServers[ i ].toLowerCase(); 
        var link = document.querySelector( 'a[title=' + currentServer + ']' ); 
        if( link != null ){
        link.click(); break
        }
    }
)();
```

*Compressed*:

```
listOfServers=["Vodlocker","Played","MovShare","NowVideo"];for(var i=0;i<listOfServers.length;i++){var currentServer=listOfServers[i].toLowerCase();var link=document.querySelector('a[title='+currentServer+']');if(link!=null){link.click();break}}
```

[Compressing website](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) (really don't think is needed but..)

So, what am I doing wrong? I'm sorry if this has been answerd, I checked a few questions and they didn't have this specific problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

-- Edit --

*Error* (if it wasn't clear)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I paste your compressed version into the Firefox console, I don't get any error.

Your compressed version is not a bookmarklet, so to test it as a bookmarklet I tried using the pattern you showed above, which is `javascript:(...)();`. When I do that, I get an error, but one that is different than you report.

Thing is, the usual pattern is `javascript:(function(){...})();`. When I used that pattern as a bookmarklet to hold your compressed code, I got no error.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know that! It worked perfectly with the pattern you gave me :)